# AndroidStudio unit tests

Tags: java, android, android-studio, view, espresso

Как протестировать работу кнопок с помощью Espresso,когда они создаются программно и их не запустить с помощью resource id.C помощью classname так же не проверить именно нужные кнопки,потомучто там куча view с одинаковыми названиями и соотвественно возникает такая ошибка: android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: 'with class name: a string containing "View"' matches multiple views in the hierarchy.
Problem views are marked with '****MATCHES****' below.

Comment: Приведите код создания кнопок, может удастся помочь.